# Plot chart using dataframe columns

Tags: pandas, charts

I have a data frame that has persons affected by two different issues for each year from 1999 to 2005 as in bellow image.
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01XtH.png)

Can I create a bar chart that shows a comparison of person affected by cancer, Heart disease for each year?

Comment: Can you copy and paste your dataframe instead of posting a picture?

Comment: Take a look at ```catplot``` https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html